# Why new 32W circular fluorescent light bulbs keeps getting blown?

Tags: fluorescent, ballast

Recently one of my ceiling light's bulb just got blown after lasting for quite a few years. I tried to replace it with a new one and the moment I turned it on, the bulb would blink once quickly say for half a second and couldn't work any more. I went on to get another bulb and install it. The same thing happened again.

Could it be the ballast that it's linked to has spoilt? I've changed the starter for the unit but it's still the same. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably the ballast, and I wouldn't replace the ballast.   For less money you can by an entire LED fixture.   [hint](http://m.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Low-Profile-White-LED-Round-Puff-CE1011-06/203725984)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's the ballast

When old magnetic ballasts go bad, that's one of the things they do.  I swear, I'm about ready to stick a logbook inside every fixture because I think most of our bulb replacements are in the same 5 fixtures.

Decide which type of bulb you want going forward (T12 vs T8) then buy an appropriate electronic ballast.

If you want to play around with some of the new LED "tubes" or fixtures, those *should* last 20 years... but there is also a lot of cheap junk out there that really won't.